# Usage of SafeStr in C

Tags: c

I am reading about using of safe strings at following location

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5111861

It is mentioned as below.

SafeStr strings, when used properly, can eliminate many of these errors and provide backward compatibility to legacy code as well.

My question is what does author mean by "provide backward compatibility to legacy code as well." ? Request to explain with example.

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that functions from the standard libc (and others) which expects plain, null terminated char arrays, will work even on those `SafeStr`s. This is probably achieved by putting a control structure at a negative offset (or some other trick) from the start of the string.

Examples: `strcmp()`  `printf()` etc can be used directly on the strings returned by SafeStr.

In contrast, there are also *other* string libraries for C which are very "smart" and dynamic, but these strings can not be sent without conversion to "old school" functions.

Answer (score 3):

From that page:

> The library is based on the safestr_t type which is completely
>   compatible with char *. This allows casting of safestr_t structures to
>   char *.

That's some backward compatibility with all the existing code that takes `char *` or `const char *` pointers.